# How to find and break sequential number and store the final elements in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Lets suppose that I have a string such as:

'the exact number of files is 223,345,129'

I am looking for a piece of code that within a sequential number like (223,345,129) wherever it found a delimiter(a comma like ",") it breaks the number into 3 elements of 223 345 129 and store these 3 segments inside an array?

Thanks for answers in advance

Comment: How would you detect the sequence within the string?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in trying to solve the issue including attempted solution(s) and encountered problem(s).

Answer (score 2):

You may do it easily with the in-built PHP function [explode](http://php.net/explode):

```
$arr = explode(",", "223,345,129");
print_r($arr);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 223
    [1] => 345
    [2] => 129
)
```

Comment: Dont you have to introduce the array in advance? like, $arr = array();

Comment: @Karl No need to introduce in advance, PHP doesn't require pre-defined variables when assigning a function output to a variable... PHP will create that variable for you.... it only becomes problematic if you want to assign output to an arbitrary key in an array when the array isn't defined in advance, or assigning to an object property when the object isn't defined